# Como uso las condiciones con el contenido de un archivo txt en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
data = open("archivo.txt", "r")
o_data = data.readlines()
data.close()
if "hola" == o_data[2]:
    print("si")
else:
    print("no")
```

el problema es que no logro saber si la palabra hola es igual al hola que esta escrito en el archivo.
Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Hola Ramphy, bienvenido a SOes. ¿Cuál es el contenido del archivo de texto? Podrías [edit] la pregunta y agregarlo por favor.

Comment: Deberías además replantear la pregunta, pensando en tu pregunta imagino que tu archivo no contiene sólo la palabra "hola" por lo que lo mas eficiente es buscar si contiene esta palabra el texto. Coméntanos realmente que necesitas y te responderemos, un ejemplo de texto no nos vendría mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es tu código:

```
data = open("archivo.txt", "r")
o_data = data.readlines()
data.close()
if "hola" == o_data[2]: # Según tú, qué debería hacer o_data[2]? 
   print("si")
else:
   print("no")
```

Un par de aclaraciones:

readlines() permite leer el contenido en una lista de lineas. Teniendo esa lista de lineas, lo que quieres hacer es leer linea por linea y mirar si existe al menos una línea que contenga la palabra "hola". Al encontrar al menos una línea que cumpla esa condición, quieres que se imprima "si". Yo propongo la siguiente solución:

```
data = open("archivo.txt", "r")
o_data = data.readlines()
for line in o_data: # Iterador que permite revisar cada línea de texto
    if "hola" in line: 
        print("si")
    else:
        print("no")
data.close() # El archivo se debe cerrar siempre al final.
```

Espero que la explicación sirva de algo. Es lo menos que se puede hacer sin tener una idea de como se ve tu archivo y sin entender la pregunta muy bien.